# How to print custom name of an operand in IDA Python?

Tags: idapython

I'm starting to work on a plugin to port symbols(stack variable names, operand names, comments, etc) from functions in one database to functions in another database when function names match.

I'm getting familiar with IDA api and now I can't find out how to get a custom name of an operand in IDA Python.

Here's my main function:
[image]

For now I'd just like to be able to print information I want, I'd like to print operand names: normal names when custom name is not defined, and the custom name when I set the custom name for the operand(Alt+F1 shortcut key by default).

Here's what I came up with for my main function:

```
import idautils


for functionItem in idautils.FuncItems(0x140012400):
    if ida_bytes.is_code(ida_bytes.get_full_flags(functionItem)):
        instruction = idautils.DecodeInstruction(functionItem)
        print(idc.print_operand(instruction.ip, 0))
```

And I expect it to print this at the end:

```
rsp
rdi
rbp:myCustomName
```

This code prints:

```
rsp
rdi
rbp
```

I tried to google but I can't find how to show custom operand name. I could only find these 2 related links:

- https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/552.shtml
- https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/477.shtml

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bunch of searches like `operand`, `manual`, `manual operand` on hex-rays's [IDA Python docs website](https://hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/), I finally managed to find the appropriate APIs needed to achieve what I want.

```
import idautils


for functionItem in idautils.FuncItems(0x140012400):
    if ida_bytes.is_code(ida_bytes.get_full_flags(functionItem)):
        instruction = idautils.DecodeInstruction(functionItem)
        if(ida_bytes.is_forced_operand(instruction.ip, 0)):
            print(ida_bytes.get_forced_operand(instruction.ip, 0))
        else:
            print(idc.print_operand(instruction.ip, 0))
```

This code above prints the desired result on IDA 7.6 with Python 3.9 installed:

```
rsp
rdi
rbp:myCustomName
```

The functions for the manual strings on instructions and operands are:

- [ida_bytes.is_manual_insn](https://hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.is_manual_insn)
- [ida_bytes.get_manual_insn](https://hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.get_manual_insn)
- [ida_bytes.set_manual_insn](https://hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.set_manual_insn)
- [ida_bytes.is_forced_operand](https://hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.is_forced_operand)
- [ida_bytes.get_forced_operand](https://hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.get_forced_operand)
- [ida_bytes.set_forced_operand](https://hex-rays.com/wp-content/static/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_bytes.html#ida_bytes.set_forced_operand)